# Activity background image with softbuttons?

Tags: android, android-activity, background

I have an app that has an activity that uses a background image the size of the activity. The main problem is it gets scaled different when the device has soft buttons (ie: home, menu, app, back, etc) vs hardware buttons.

Is there a way I can take into account the device using soft buttons? I had thought about using the -hNNN resource modifier, but somehow I doubt that's the correct method.

I suppose one option is to always scale to the full height, even under the title and softbuttons, but still not hide them (or even make them translucent, if that's possible). Another option is to just split the background into two parts. the top, which is longer than needed, to cover height differences, and the bottom part where buttons go.

Comment: You should certainly not have a background image that expects a certain device size. There are a lot of devices out there with different sizes. You can use a 9-patch background, or maybe a solid color background with an image on top of that.

Comment: The current design doesn't lead to something that will work as a 9patch image, or a floating logo style screen. It's a full width, and height full colour picture. I could tell the designer to completely redesign everything, but they may not like that.